# How to programatically get the list of projects in the NetBeans IDE?

Tags: netbeans

How to programmatically get the list of projects added to the default workspace in the NetBeans?
In Eclipse, I can get it through ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects()

In NetBeans API documentation, references to 'workspace' are marked 'deprecated' and I couldn't find a way to achieve this by searching NetBeans website, stackoverflow, etc.

For each project in the list, I'd like to use various APIs from "org.netbeans.api.project" (Project API). The NetBeans Project API seems to be useful for a particular project that I can refer to but I'd need to have the list of projects to be able to use it.

Thanks,
VKN

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To receive better help, show us what code you have attempted. Read more about how to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OpenProjects](http://bits.netbeans.org/8.0/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-projectuiapi/org/netbeans/api/project/ui/OpenProjects.html) is the closest to what you are looking for. Except there is no exact counterpart to Eclipse's workspace in NetBeans and open project does not have same meaning as in Eclipse.

Comment: I tried using OpenProjects.getDefault().getOpenProjects() but it doesn't return anything when I run it, I think because the code runs in the new instance of NetBeans which doesn't have any projects. So how to run the code that accesses the projects within the original instance of the NetBeans IDE?

Comment: Build a NetBeans plugin and install it into your NetBeans (in plugin manager there is a possibility to install downloaded modules saved as *.nbm files on disk).